# x-axis with more than one factor groups ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I am a newbie to R. I have climate data, as presented in few lines below. The data indicate temperature change with respect to historical climate. I want to create a box plot (ggplot) which looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to create this kind of plot. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
DATE        TMAX        TMIN
1/1/2010    2.927586207 0.627586207
1/2/2010    0.827586207 0.824137931
1/3/2010    2.031034483 0.55862069
1/4/2010    2.648275862 0.7
1/5/2010    2.196551724 0.393103448
1/6/2010    1.220689655 0.5
1/7/2010    1.224137931 0.813793103
1/8/2010    1.94137931  1.05862069
1/9/2010    2.648275862 0.875862069
1/10/2010   0.637931034 0.817241379
1/11/2010   2.444827586 0.827586207
1/12/2010   0.072413793 0.634482759
1/13/2010   -0.320689655    0.755172414
1/14/2010   0.606896552 1.113793103
1/15/2010   1.544827586 1.151724138
1/16/2010   1.017241379 0.775862069
1/17/2010   1.237931034 0.986206897
1/18/2010   1.086206897 0.689655172
1/19/2010   -0.324137931    0.548275862
1/20/2010   -0.410344828    0.451724138
1/21/2010   0.624137931 0.837931034
1/22/2010   -1.424137931    0.789655172
1/23/2010   0.917241379 0.6
1/24/2010   -1.144827586    0.751724138
1/25/2010   0.289655172 0.365517241
1/26/2010   0.313793103 0.110344828
1/27/2010   -1.54137931 0.251724138
1/28/2010   0.162068966 0.251724138
1/29/2010   -0.04137931 0.268965517
1/30/2010   -1.120689655    0.293103448
1/31/2010   1.386206897 0.582758621
2/1/2010    1.062068966 0.906896552
2/2/2010    0.503448276 0.979310345
2/3/2010    0.462068966 0.817241379
2/4/2010    0.455172414 0.817241379
2/5/2010    0.662068966 0.424137931
2/6/2010    0.272413793 0.74137931
2/7/2010    -0.020689655    0.348275862
2/8/2010    0.175862069 -0.05862069
2/9/2010    0.362068966 0.331034483
2/10/2010   0.744827586 0.617241379
2/11/2010   0.427586207 0.796551724
2/12/2010   0.348275862 0.903448276
2/13/2010   0.765517241 0.920689655
2/14/2010   -0.05862069 0.424137931
2/15/2010   0.055172414 0.610344828
2/16/2010   0.372413793 0.424137931
2/17/2010   0.934482759 0.479310345
2/18/2010   0.244827586 0.210344828
2/19/2010   0.831034483 0.486206897
2/20/2010   0.572413793 0.648275862
2/21/2010   0.65862069  0.331034483
2/22/2010   0.34137931  0.393103448
2/23/2010   0.4 0.668965517
2/24/2010   0.7 0.272413793
2/25/2010   1.231034483 0.593103448
2/26/2010   0.648275862 1.103448276
2/27/2010   0.220689655 1.193103448
2/28/2010   -0.14137931 1.027586207
3/1/2010    0.924137931 1.286206897
3/2/2010    -0.224137931    0.127586207
3/3/2010    0.696551724 0.279310345
3/4/2010    -0.513793103    0.237931034
3/5/2010    -0.924137931    0.306896552
3/6/2010    -0.327586207    0.4
3/7/2010    -1.334482759    0.910344828
3/8/2010    -1.627586207    0.84137931
3/9/2010    0.093103448 0.668965517
3/10/2010   0.589655172 0.762068966
3/11/2010   0.282758621 0.751724138
3/12/2010   0.575862069 1.134482759
3/13/2010   -0.003448276    1.403448276
3/14/2010   0.103448276 2.617241379
3/15/2010   0.5 3.389655172
3/16/2010   -0.017241379    1.220689655
3/17/2010   -0.103448276    0.434482759
3/18/2010   -0.110344828    0.362068966
3/19/2010   0.289655172 3.55E-15
3/20/2010   0.603448276 1.044827586
3/21/2010   1.189655172 1.096551724
3/22/2010   0.375862069 0.631034483
3/23/2010   0.475862069 0.831034483
3/24/2010   0.279310345 1.234482759
3/25/2010   -0.034482759    0.85862069
3/26/2010   0.286206897 0.886206897
3/27/2010   0.789655172 0.896551724
3/28/2010   0.789655172 0.734482759
3/29/2010   0.989655172 1.05862069
3/30/2010   0.572413793 0.737931034
3/31/2010   0.982758621 0.455172414
4/1/2010    0.372413793 0.586206897
4/2/2010    0.35862069  1.055172414
4/3/2010    0.35862069  0.855172414
4/4/2010    0.979310345 1.079310345
4/5/2010    0.568965517 0.968965517
4/6/2010    0.572413793 1.075862069
4/7/2010    0.768965517 0.862068966
4/8/2010    0.689655172 0.679310345
4/9/2010    0.979310345 0.572413793
4/10/2010   1.265517241 0.651724138
4/11/2010   0.979310345 0.468965517
4/12/2010   0.262068966 1.048275862
4/13/2010   0.862068966 1.048275862
4/14/2010   0.675862069 0.962068966
4/15/2010   0.975862069 0.872413793
4/16/2010   1.572413793 0.762068966
4/17/2010   2.375862069 0.968965517
4/18/2010   -0.248275862    1.14137931
4/19/2010   1.486206897 0.593103448
4/20/2010   0.868965517 0.762068966
4/21/2010   -0.813793103    0.2
4/22/2010   0.879310345 0.382758621
4/23/2010   1.079310345 0.703448276
4/24/2010   0.851724138 1.044827586
4/25/2010   1.6 0.696551724
4/26/2010   0.586206897 0.486206897
4/27/2010   1.079310345 0.665517241
4/28/2010   1.089655172 0.889655172
4/29/2010   0.886206897 0.596551724
4/30/2010   1.079310345 0.496551724
5/1/2010    1.293103448 0.789655172
5/2/2010    0.796551724 0.427586207
5/3/2010    1.206896552 0.34137931
5/4/2010    0.748275862 0.479310345
5/5/2010    1.006896552 0.355172414
5/6/2010    1.106896552 0.348275862
5/7/2010    0.889655172 0.427586207
5/8/2010    1.020689655 0.262068966
5/9/2010    0.934482759 0.368965517
5/10/2010   1.017241379 0.54137931
5/11/2010   0.817241379 0.644827586
5/12/2010   1.34137931  0.382758621
5/13/2010   0.913793103 0.35862069
5/14/2010   0.903448276 0.25862069
5/15/2010   0.527586207 0.679310345
5/16/2010   0.893103448 0.220689655
5/17/2010   0.806896552 0.35862069
5/18/2010   1.017241379 0.248275862
5/19/2010   0.717241379 -0.117241379
5/20/2010   0.631034483 0.482758621
5/21/2010   0.613793103 0.268965517
5/22/2010   0.331034483 0.193103448
5/23/2010   0.54137931  0.3
5/24/2010   0.720689655 -0.8
5/25/2010   0.789655172 -0.027586207
5/26/2010   0.934482759 -0.903448276
5/27/2010   0.927586207 0.265517241
5/28/2010   1.127586207 0.765517241
5/29/2010   1.027586207 0.565517241
5/30/2010   1.027586207 0.386206897
5/31/2010   0.924137931 -0.175862069
6/1/2010    0.603448276 0.193103448
6/2/2010    0.644827586 0.486206897
6/3/2010    0.727586207 0.375862069
6/4/2010    1.14137931  0.506896552
6/5/2010    1.034482759 0.255172414
6/6/2010    0.631034483 -0.289655172
6/7/2010    0.74137931  -0.265517241
6/8/2010    0.644827586 -0.082758621
6/9/2010    1.14137931  0.793103448
6/10/2010   0.827586207 0.937931034
6/11/2010   1.434482759 0.744827586
6/12/2010   1.248275862 0.979310345
6/13/2010   0.637931034 0.193103448
6/14/2010   0.644827586 -0.065517241
6/15/2010   0.731034483 -0.196551724
6/16/2010   0.951724138 0.120689655
6/17/2010   0.851724138 1.427586207
6/18/2010   0.737931034 -0.124137931
6/19/2010   1.04137931  -0.017241379
6/20/2010   0.734482759 -0.189655172
6/21/2010   0.931034483 0.331034483
6/22/2010   0.851724138 0.962068966
6/23/2010   1.444827586 0.465517241
6/24/2010   1.165517241 -0.24137931
6/25/2010   1.162068966 0.334482759
6/26/2010   0.951724138 0.451724138
6/27/2010   1.051724138 0.331034483
6/28/2010   0.931034483 0.1
6/29/2010   1.424137931 1.034482759
6/30/2010   1.648275862 0.668965517
7/1/2010    1.031034483 0.168965517
7/2/2010    0.331034483 -0.844827586
7/3/2010    0.562068966 -0.617241379
7/4/2010    0.265517241 -0.713793103
7/5/2010    0.448275862 0.079310345
7/6/2010    0.837931034 -0.368965517
7/7/2010    0.662068966 0.455172414
7/8/2010    0.548275862 0.244827586
7/9/2010    0.575862069 0.382758621
7/10/2010   0.651724138 0.210344828
7/11/2010   0.472413793 0.444827586
7/12/2010   0.665517241 0.079310345
7/13/2010   0.851724138 0.686206897
7/14/2010   0.772413793 0.824137931
7/15/2010   1.148275862 -0.034482759
7/16/2010   1.365517241 -0.006896552
7/17/2010   1.155172414 -0.486206897
7/18/2010   1.634482759 0.117241379
7/19/2010   0.868965517 0.637931034
7/20/2010   0.965517241 0.54137931
7/21/2010   1.072413793 0.272413793
7/22/2010   1.134482759 0.110344828
7/23/2010   1.562068966 0.451724138
7/24/2010   0.575862069 1.248275862
7/25/2010   0.648275862 0.751724138
7/26/2010   1.25862069  0.793103448
7/27/2010   1.05862069  1.013793103
7/28/2010   0.75862069  1.055172414
7/29/2010   1.265517241 0.682758621
7/30/2010   0.637931034 0.451724138
7/31/2010   1.251724138 0.817241379
8/1/2010    1.44137931  0.344827586
8/2/2010    0.862068966 0.479310345
8/3/2010    0.610344828 -0.031034483
8/4/2010    0.84137931  0.25862069
8/5/2010    0.748275862 0.065517241
8/6/2010    0.217241379 0.420689655
8/7/2010    1.055172414 0.489655172
8/8/2010    0.717241379 0.520689655
8/9/2010    0.827586207 0.524137931
8/10/2010   1.010344828 0.3
8/11/2010   1.024137931 0.351724138
8/12/2010   1.05862069  0.589655172
8/13/2010   1.975862069 0.05862069
8/14/2010   1.465517241 0.306896552
8/15/2010   1.475862069 0.672413793
8/16/2010   1.534482759 0.55862069
8/17/2010   0.934482759 -0.124137931
8/18/2010   0.906896552 1.103448276
8/19/2010   0.720689655 0.737931034
8/20/2010   1.227586207 0.765517241
8/21/2010   1.051724138 0.982758621
8/22/2010   1.14137931  0.434482759
8/23/2010   1.265517241 0.255172414
8/24/2010   1.355172414 0.651724138
8/25/2010   1.793103448 0.613793103
8/26/2010   1.362068966 0.572413793
8/27/2010   1.262068966 0.362068966
8/28/2010   1.482758621 0.306896552
8/29/2010   1.079310345 0.286206897
8/30/2010   1.286206897 0.610344828
8/31/2010   1.382758621 0.379310345
9/1/2010    1.672413793 0.803448276
9/2/2010    0.817241379 -0.320689655
9/3/2010    1.720689655 0.406896552
9/4/2010    1.296551724 0.203448276
9/5/2010    1.296551724 0.424137931
9/6/2010    1.879310345 0.179310345
9/7/2010    1.579310345 0.393103448
9/8/2010    1.468965517 0.172413793
9/9/2010    1.468965517 0.268965517
9/10/2010   1.182758621 0.482758621
9/11/2010   1.106896552 0.503448276
9/12/2010   1.503448276 0.403448276
9/13/2010   0.903448276 0.2
9/14/2010   1.179310345 0.25862069
9/15/2010   1.175862069 -0.003448276
9/16/2010   1.075862069 0.306896552
9/17/2010   1.082758621 0.317241379
9/18/2010   1.165517241 -0.224137931
9/19/2010   1.551724138 0.734482759
9/20/2010   1.9 -0.272413793
9/21/2010   0.962068966 0.175862069
9/22/2010   0.765517241 0.293103448
9/23/2010   0.951724138 0.444827586
9/24/2010   1.455172414 0.027586207
9/25/2010   0.95862069  0.762068966
9/26/2010   0.693103448 0.703448276
9/27/2010   0.786206897 0.182758621
9/28/2010   1.355172414 0.124137931
9/29/2010   1.451724138 0.513793103
9/30/2010   1.134482759 0.9
10/1/2010   1.420689655 0.613793103
10/2/2010   0.755172414 -0.193103448
10/3/2010   0.148275862 -0.413793103
10/4/2010   0.65862069  0.106896552
10/5/2010   0.872413793 -0.282758621
10/6/2010   0.668965517 -0.279310345
10/7/2010   0.775862069 0.203448276
10/8/2010   0.968965517 -0.010344828
10/9/2010   0.903448276 0.224137931
10/10/2010  0.879310345 -0.086206897
10/11/2010  1.203448276 -0.051724138
10/12/2010  0.575862069 -0.072413793
10/13/2010  0.689655172 0.327586207
10/14/2010  0.603448276 -0.162068966
10/15/2010  1.096551724 0.313793103
10/16/2010  1.2 0.634482759
10/17/2010  1.103448276 0.437931034
10/18/2010  1.520689655 -0.368965517
10/19/2010  1.537931034 0.586206897
10/20/2010  1.1 0.651724138
10/21/2010  1.589655172 0.648275862
10/22/2010  1.027586207 0.162068966
10/23/2010  1.213793103 0.551724138
10/24/2010  1.444827586 0.668965517
10/25/2010  1.227586207 0.579310345
10/26/2010  1.5 0.231034483
10/27/2010  0.762068966 0.293103448
10/28/2010  1.651724138 -0.224137931
10/29/2010  0.010344828 -0.25862069
10/30/2010  1.724137931 0.365517241
10/31/2010  0.589655172 0.424137931
11/1/2010   0.9 -0.472413793
11/2/2010   1.286206897 0.034482759
11/3/2010   1.15862069  0.179310345
11/4/2010   1.568965517 0.403448276
11/5/2010   1.168965517 -0.003448276
11/6/2010   1.472413793 0.4
11/7/2010   1.165517241 0.696551724
11/8/2010   1.572413793 0.472413793
11/9/2010   1.317241379 0.144827586
11/10/2010  0.931034483 -0.137931034
11/11/2010  1.355172414 -0.017241379
11/12/2010  1.055172414 0.4
11/13/2010  1.668965517 0.220689655
11/14/2010  1.889655172 0.810344828
11/15/2010  2.275862069 0.172413793
11/16/2010  1.451724138 0.365517241
11/17/2010  2.544827586 0.44137931
11/18/2010  1.05862069  0.479310345
11/19/2010  0.737931034 0.255172414
11/20/2010  1.162068966 -7.11E-15
11/21/2010  1.562068966 0.193103448
11/22/2010  1.448275862 0.410344828
11/23/2010  1.951724138 0.679310345
11/24/2010  0.248275862 0.282758621
11/25/2010  1.648275862 0.196551724
11/26/2010  2.365517241 -0.172413793
11/27/2010  1.562068966 -0.131034483
11/28/2010  1.462068966 -0.120689655
11/29/2010  1.362068966 0.568965517
11/30/2010  1.293103448 0.710344828
12/1/2010   2.803448276 0.231034483
12/2/2010   4.34137931  0.717241379
12/3/2010   1.234482759 0.003448276
12/4/2010   1.486206897 -0.044827586
12/5/2010   1.162068966 0.220689655
12/6/2010   0.286206897 0.293103448
12/7/2010   1.175862069 0.189655172
12/8/2010   1.124137931 0.248275862
12/9/2010   0.486206897 -0.172413793
12/10/2010  0.996551724 0.420689655
12/11/2010  0.082758621 -0.248275862
12/12/2010  0.724137931 -0.093103448
12/13/2010  0.993103448 -0.006896552
12/14/2010  1.379310345 -0.020689655
12/15/2010  0.275862069 0.189655172
12/16/2010  0.772413793 0.068965517
12/17/2010  1.482758621 0.175862069
12/18/2010  1.15862069  0.548275862
12/19/2010  -0.137931034    0.562068966
12/20/2010  2.006896552 0.037931034
12/21/2010  0.424137931 0.293103448
12/22/2010  0.517241379 0.303448276
12/23/2010  0.817241379 0.027586207
12/24/2010  0.620689655 0.210344828
12/25/2010  1.703448276 0.368965517
12/26/2010  0.034482759 0.3
12/27/2010  0.713793103 0.027586207
12/28/2010  1.131034483 0.068965517
12/29/2010  2.806896552 -0.168965517
12/30/2010  1.117241379 0.296551724
12/31/2010  0.848275862 0.420689655
1/1/2011    1.810344828 0.086206897
1/2/2011    0.248275862 0.168965517
1/3/2011    2.027586207 0.903448276
1/4/2011    1.448275862 0.634482759
1/5/2011    1.013793103 0.186206897
1/6/2011    1.455172414 0.103448276
1/7/2011    0.820689655 0.65862069
1/8/2011    4.762068966 0.010344828
1/9/2011    1.986206897 0.724137931
1/10/2011   0.231034483 0.65862069
1/11/2011   2.220689655 0.45862069
1/12/2011   2.248275862 0.472413793
1/13/2011   1.137931034 0.479310345
1/14/2011   1.555172414 0.510344828
1/15/2011   1.268965517 1.255172414
1/16/2011   1.186206897 1.134482759
1/17/2011   0.772413793 0.713793103
1/18/2011   1.337931034 0.575862069
1/19/2011   -0.351724138    0.417241379
1/20/2011   0.586206897 0.724137931
1/21/2011   1.117241379 0.682758621
1/22/2011   -0.151724138    0.596551724
1/23/2011   -0.420689655    -0.010344828
1/24/2011   0.486206897 0.096551724
1/25/2011   -1.05862069 0.517241379
1/26/2011   0.275862069 0.613793103
1/27/2011   1.317241379 0.165517241
1/28/2011   0.44137931  0.568965517
1/29/2011   -1.120689655    0.362068966
1/30/2011   1.689655172 0.693103448
1/31/2011   -0.337931034    0.889655172
2/1/2011    -1.444827586    0.372413793
2/2/2011    -0.044827586    -0.075862069
2/3/2011    1.231034483 0.593103448
2/4/2011    0.796551724 0.565517241
2/5/2011    0.110344828 0.682758621
2/6/2011    0.84137931  0.496551724
2/7/2011    -0.55862069 0.720689655
2/8/2011    0.862068966 0.720689655
2/9/2011    0.117241379 0.382758621
2/10/2011   0.065517241 0.637931034
2/11/2011   0.8 1.072413793
2/12/2011   0.424137931 0.793103448
2/13/2011   1   0.85862069
2/14/2011   1.006896552 0.85862069
2/15/2011   -0.906896552    0.548275862
2/16/2011   0.324137931 0.503448276
2/17/2011   0.817241379 0.486206897
2/18/2011   0.137931034 0.706896552
2/19/2011   0.396551724 0.84137931
2/20/2011   -0.144827586    1.024137931
2/21/2011   0.9 1.162068966
2/22/2011   1.293103448 0.34137931
2/23/2011   1.603448276 -0.324137931
```

Comment: A good place to start with boxplots using `ggplot2` is the package reference material, [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html), which is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

I borrowed some parts from the other answers and pasted them together. The unique part is the `facet_grid`. Therefore I replicated the data using an index column `gr` which is used for the facet function.

```
df %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Month = as.numeric(format(as.Date(DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m"))) %>% 
  mutate(Season = case_when(Month %in% 10:12 ~ "OND",
                            Month %in%  1:3 ~ "JFM",
                            Month %in%  4:6  ~ "AMJ",
                            TRUE ~ "JAS")) %>% 
  select(Month, Season, TMAX) %>% 
  mutate(gr=1) %>% 
  bind_rows(.,mutate(.,gr=2)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.,filter(., gr==1) %>%  mutate(gr=3)) %>% 
  mutate(X=factor(ifelse(gr==1, Month, ifelse(gr==2, Season, "Ya")), 
         levels = c(1:12, "JFM", "AMJ", "JAS", "OND", "Ya"))) %>% 
  mutate(gr=ifelse(gr==3,2,gr)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = X, y = TMAX)) +
     geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "grey60", outlier.shape = 1) +
     stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  
     stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 2, color = "red", shape = 0) + 
     stat_summary(data=. %>% filter(gr==1),fun.y = mean, geom = "line", color = "red",aes(group = 1)) +
     facet_grid(~gr, scales = "free_x", space = "free") +
     theme(strip.background = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant application of `facet_grid`! Very nice:-)

Comment: Very elegant indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to your desired output

```r
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# Create DATE, Month, Year and Season 
df1 <- df %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y"),
         Month = month(DATE),
         Year  = year(DATE)) %>% 
  mutate(Season = case_when(Month %in% 10:12 ~ "OND",
                          Month %in%  1:3  ~ "JFM",
                          Month %in%  4:6  ~ "AMJ",
                          TRUE ~ "JAS"
                          ))
df1

#> # A tibble: 419 x 6
#>    DATE        TMAX  TMIN Month  Year Season
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#>  1 2010-01-01 2.93  0.628     1  2010 JFM   
#>  2 2010-01-02 0.828 0.824     1  2010 JFM   
#>  3 2010-01-03 2.03  0.559     1  2010 JFM   
#>  4 2010-01-04 2.65  0.7       1  2010 JFM   
#>  5 2010-01-05 2.20  0.393     1  2010 JFM   
#>  6 2010-01-06 1.22  0.5       1  2010 JFM   
#>  7 2010-01-07 1.22  0.814     1  2010 JFM   
#>  8 2010-01-08 1.94  1.06      1  2010 JFM   
#>  9 2010-01-09 2.65  0.876     1  2010 JFM   
#> 10 2010-01-10 0.638 0.817     1  2010 JFM   
#> # ... with 409 more rows


# Calculate Seasonal and annual average
tmax_season <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year, Season) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
tmax_season

#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>    Year Season  TMAX  TMIN Month
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2010 AMJ    0.894 0.463  5   
#> 2  2010 JAS    1.08  0.355  7.99
#> 3  2010 JFM    0.479 0.725  2   
#> 4  2010 OND    1.18  0.202 11   
#> 5  2011 JFM    0.734 0.556  1.43

tmax_annual <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Season = "Ya")
tmax_annual

#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>    Year  TMAX  TMIN Month Season
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1  2010 0.912 0.434  6.53 Ya    
#> 2  2011 0.734 0.556  1.43 Ya

# Merge together & set the correct order of the season
tmax_ave <- bind_rows(tmax_season, tmax_annual) %>% 
  mutate(Season = factor(Season, levels = c("JFM", "AMJ", "JAS", "OND", "Ya")))

# Plot mean monthly
plt1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = factor(Month), y = TMAX)) +
  labs(title = "Changes of Max temperature") +
  ylab(expression("T"[max]~(degree*C))) +
  xlab("Month") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "grey60", outlier.shape = 1) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 2, color = "red", shape = 0) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1))  + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.85))

# Plot Seasonal and annual average
plt2 <- ggplot(tmax_ave, aes(x = Season, y = TMAX)) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "grey60", outlier.shape = 1) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 2, color = "red", shape = 0) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())

# Combine plots
cowplot::plot_grid(plt1 + theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 5.5, r = 0,
                                                     l = 5.5, b = 5.5)), 
                   plt2 + theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 5.5, r = 5.5,
                                                     l =   0, b = 5.5)), 
                   ncol = 2,
                   align = "h",
                   axis = "tb",
                   rel_widths = c(2.0, 1.0))
#> Warning: Removed 36 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
#> Warning: Removed 36 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
#> Warning: Removed 36 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).

#> Warning: Removed 36 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Data used:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "DATE        TMAX        TMIN
1/1/2010    2.927586207 0.627586207
1/2/2010    0.827586207 0.824137931
1/3/2010    2.031034483 0.55862069
1/4/2010    2.648275862 0.7
1/5/2010    2.196551724 0.393103448
1/6/2010    1.220689655 0.5
1/7/2010    1.224137931 0.813793103
1/8/2010    1.94137931  1.05862069
1/9/2010    2.648275862 0.875862069
1/10/2010   0.637931034 0.817241379
1/11/2010   2.444827586 0.827586207
1/12/2010   0.072413793 0.634482759
1/13/2010   -0.320689655    0.755172414
1/14/2010   0.606896552 1.113793103
1/15/2010   1.544827586 1.151724138
1/16/2010   1.017241379 0.775862069
1/17/2010   1.237931034 0.986206897
1/18/2010   1.086206897 0.689655172
1/19/2010   -0.324137931    0.548275862
1/20/2010   -0.410344828    0.451724138
1/21/2010   0.624137931 0.837931034
1/22/2010   -1.424137931    0.789655172
1/23/2010   0.917241379 0.6
1/24/2010   -1.144827586    0.751724138
1/25/2010   0.289655172 0.365517241
1/26/2010   0.313793103 0.110344828
1/27/2010   -1.54137931 0.251724138
1/28/2010   0.162068966 0.251724138
1/29/2010   -0.04137931 0.268965517
1/30/2010   -1.120689655    0.293103448
1/31/2010   1.386206897 0.582758621
2/1/2010    1.062068966 0.906896552
2/2/2010    0.503448276 0.979310345
2/3/2010    0.462068966 0.817241379
2/4/2010    0.455172414 0.817241379
2/5/2010    0.662068966 0.424137931
2/6/2010    0.272413793 0.74137931
2/7/2010    -0.020689655    0.348275862
2/8/2010    0.175862069 -0.05862069
2/9/2010    0.362068966 0.331034483
2/10/2010   0.744827586 0.617241379
2/11/2010   0.427586207 0.796551724
2/12/2010   0.348275862 0.903448276
2/13/2010   0.765517241 0.920689655
2/14/2010   -0.05862069 0.424137931
2/15/2010   0.055172414 0.610344828
2/16/2010   0.372413793 0.424137931
2/17/2010   0.934482759 0.479310345
2/18/2010   0.244827586 0.210344828
2/19/2010   0.831034483 0.486206897
2/20/2010   0.572413793 0.648275862
2/21/2010   0.65862069  0.331034483
2/22/2010   0.34137931  0.393103448
2/23/2010   0.4 0.668965517
2/24/2010   0.7 0.272413793
2/25/2010   1.231034483 0.593103448
2/26/2010   0.648275862 1.103448276
2/27/2010   0.220689655 1.193103448
2/28/2010   -0.14137931 1.027586207
3/1/2010    0.924137931 1.286206897
3/2/2010    -0.224137931    0.127586207
3/3/2010    0.696551724 0.279310345
3/4/2010    -0.513793103    0.237931034
3/5/2010    -0.924137931    0.306896552
3/6/2010    -0.327586207    0.4
3/7/2010    -1.334482759    0.910344828
3/8/2010    -1.627586207    0.84137931
3/9/2010    0.093103448 0.668965517
3/10/2010   0.589655172 0.762068966
3/11/2010   0.282758621 0.751724138
3/12/2010   0.575862069 1.134482759
3/13/2010   -0.003448276    1.403448276
3/14/2010   0.103448276 2.617241379
3/15/2010   0.5 3.389655172
3/16/2010   -0.017241379    1.220689655
3/17/2010   -0.103448276    0.434482759
3/18/2010   -0.110344828    0.362068966
3/19/2010   0.289655172 3.55E-15
3/20/2010   0.603448276 1.044827586
3/21/2010   1.189655172 1.096551724
3/22/2010   0.375862069 0.631034483
3/23/2010   0.475862069 0.831034483
3/24/2010   0.279310345 1.234482759
3/25/2010   -0.034482759    0.85862069
3/26/2010   0.286206897 0.886206897
3/27/2010   0.789655172 0.896551724
3/28/2010   0.789655172 0.734482759
3/29/2010   0.989655172 1.05862069
3/30/2010   0.572413793 0.737931034
3/31/2010   0.982758621 0.455172414
4/1/2010    0.372413793 0.586206897
4/2/2010    0.35862069  1.055172414
4/3/2010    0.35862069  0.855172414
4/4/2010    0.979310345 1.079310345
4/5/2010    0.568965517 0.968965517
4/6/2010    0.572413793 1.075862069
4/7/2010    0.768965517 0.862068966
4/8/2010    0.689655172 0.679310345
4/9/2010    0.979310345 0.572413793
4/10/2010   1.265517241 0.651724138
4/11/2010   0.979310345 0.468965517
4/12/2010   0.262068966 1.048275862
4/13/2010   0.862068966 1.048275862
4/14/2010   0.675862069 0.962068966
4/15/2010   0.975862069 0.872413793
4/16/2010   1.572413793 0.762068966
4/17/2010   2.375862069 0.968965517
4/18/2010   -0.248275862    1.14137931
4/19/2010   1.486206897 0.593103448
4/20/2010   0.868965517 0.762068966
4/21/2010   -0.813793103    0.2
4/22/2010   0.879310345 0.382758621
4/23/2010   1.079310345 0.703448276
4/24/2010   0.851724138 1.044827586
4/25/2010   1.6 0.696551724
4/26/2010   0.586206897 0.486206897
4/27/2010   1.079310345 0.665517241
4/28/2010   1.089655172 0.889655172
4/29/2010   0.886206897 0.596551724
4/30/2010   1.079310345 0.496551724
5/1/2010    1.293103448 0.789655172
5/2/2010    0.796551724 0.427586207
5/3/2010    1.206896552 0.34137931
5/4/2010    0.748275862 0.479310345
5/5/2010    1.006896552 0.355172414
5/6/2010    1.106896552 0.348275862
5/7/2010    0.889655172 0.427586207
5/8/2010    1.020689655 0.262068966
5/9/2010    0.934482759 0.368965517
5/10/2010   1.017241379 0.54137931
5/11/2010   0.817241379 0.644827586
5/12/2010   1.34137931  0.382758621
5/13/2010   0.913793103 0.35862069
5/14/2010   0.903448276 0.25862069
5/15/2010   0.527586207 0.679310345
5/16/2010   0.893103448 0.220689655
5/17/2010   0.806896552 0.35862069
5/18/2010   1.017241379 0.248275862
5/19/2010   0.717241379 -0.117241379
5/20/2010   0.631034483 0.482758621
5/21/2010   0.613793103 0.268965517
5/22/2010   0.331034483 0.193103448
5/23/2010   0.54137931  0.3
5/24/2010   0.720689655 -0.8
5/25/2010   0.789655172 -0.027586207
5/26/2010   0.934482759 -0.903448276
5/27/2010   0.927586207 0.265517241
5/28/2010   1.127586207 0.765517241
5/29/2010   1.027586207 0.565517241
5/30/2010   1.027586207 0.386206897
5/31/2010   0.924137931 -0.175862069
6/1/2010    0.603448276 0.193103448
6/2/2010    0.644827586 0.486206897
6/3/2010    0.727586207 0.375862069
6/4/2010    1.14137931  0.506896552
6/5/2010    1.034482759 0.255172414
6/6/2010    0.631034483 -0.289655172
6/7/2010    0.74137931  -0.265517241
6/8/2010    0.644827586 -0.082758621
6/9/2010    1.14137931  0.793103448
6/10/2010   0.827586207 0.937931034
6/11/2010   1.434482759 0.744827586
6/12/2010   1.248275862 0.979310345
6/13/2010   0.637931034 0.193103448
6/14/2010   0.644827586 -0.065517241
6/15/2010   0.731034483 -0.196551724
6/16/2010   0.951724138 0.120689655
6/17/2010   0.851724138 1.427586207
6/18/2010   0.737931034 -0.124137931
6/19/2010   1.04137931  -0.017241379
6/20/2010   0.734482759 -0.189655172
6/21/2010   0.931034483 0.331034483
6/22/2010   0.851724138 0.962068966
6/23/2010   1.444827586 0.465517241
6/24/2010   1.165517241 -0.24137931
6/25/2010   1.162068966 0.334482759
6/26/2010   0.951724138 0.451724138
6/27/2010   1.051724138 0.331034483
6/28/2010   0.931034483 0.1
6/29/2010   1.424137931 1.034482759
6/30/2010   1.648275862 0.668965517
7/1/2010    1.031034483 0.168965517
7/2/2010    0.331034483 -0.844827586
7/3/2010    0.562068966 -0.617241379
7/4/2010    0.265517241 -0.713793103
7/5/2010    0.448275862 0.079310345
7/6/2010    0.837931034 -0.368965517
7/7/2010    0.662068966 0.455172414
7/8/2010    0.548275862 0.244827586
7/9/2010    0.575862069 0.382758621
7/10/2010   0.651724138 0.210344828
7/11/2010   0.472413793 0.444827586
7/12/2010   0.665517241 0.079310345
7/13/2010   0.851724138 0.686206897
7/14/2010   0.772413793 0.824137931
7/15/2010   1.148275862 -0.034482759
7/16/2010   1.365517241 -0.006896552
7/17/2010   1.155172414 -0.486206897
7/18/2010   1.634482759 0.117241379
7/19/2010   0.868965517 0.637931034
7/20/2010   0.965517241 0.54137931
7/21/2010   1.072413793 0.272413793
7/22/2010   1.134482759 0.110344828
7/23/2010   1.562068966 0.451724138
7/24/2010   0.575862069 1.248275862
7/25/2010   0.648275862 0.751724138
7/26/2010   1.25862069  0.793103448
7/27/2010   1.05862069  1.013793103
7/28/2010   0.75862069  1.055172414
7/29/2010   1.265517241 0.682758621
7/30/2010   0.637931034 0.451724138
7/31/2010   1.251724138 0.817241379
8/1/2010    1.44137931  0.344827586
8/2/2010    0.862068966 0.479310345
8/3/2010    0.610344828 -0.031034483
8/4/2010    0.84137931  0.25862069
8/5/2010    0.748275862 0.065517241
8/6/2010    0.217241379 0.420689655
8/7/2010    1.055172414 0.489655172
8/8/2010    0.717241379 0.520689655
8/9/2010    0.827586207 0.524137931
8/10/2010   1.010344828 0.3
8/11/2010   1.024137931 0.351724138
8/12/2010   1.05862069  0.589655172
8/13/2010   1.975862069 0.05862069
8/14/2010   1.465517241 0.306896552
8/15/2010   1.475862069 0.672413793
8/16/2010   1.534482759 0.55862069
8/17/2010   0.934482759 -0.124137931
8/18/2010   0.906896552 1.103448276
8/19/2010   0.720689655 0.737931034
8/20/2010   1.227586207 0.765517241
8/21/2010   1.051724138 0.982758621
8/22/2010   1.14137931  0.434482759
8/23/2010   1.265517241 0.255172414
8/24/2010   1.355172414 0.651724138
8/25/2010   1.793103448 0.613793103
8/26/2010   1.362068966 0.572413793
8/27/2010   1.262068966 0.362068966
8/28/2010   1.482758621 0.306896552
8/29/2010   1.079310345 0.286206897
8/30/2010   1.286206897 0.610344828
8/31/2010   1.382758621 0.379310345
9/1/2010    1.672413793 0.803448276
9/2/2010    0.817241379 -0.320689655
9/3/2010    1.720689655 0.406896552
9/4/2010    1.296551724 0.203448276
9/5/2010    1.296551724 0.424137931
9/6/2010    1.879310345 0.179310345
9/7/2010    1.579310345 0.393103448
9/8/2010    1.468965517 0.172413793
9/9/2010    1.468965517 0.268965517
9/10/2010   1.182758621 0.482758621
9/11/2010   1.106896552 0.503448276
9/12/2010   1.503448276 0.403448276
9/13/2010   0.903448276 0.2
9/14/2010   1.179310345 0.25862069
9/15/2010   1.175862069 -0.003448276
9/16/2010   1.075862069 0.306896552
9/17/2010   1.082758621 0.317241379
9/18/2010   1.165517241 -0.224137931
9/19/2010   1.551724138 0.734482759
9/20/2010   1.9 -0.272413793
9/21/2010   0.962068966 0.175862069
9/22/2010   0.765517241 0.293103448
9/23/2010   0.951724138 0.444827586
9/24/2010   1.455172414 0.027586207
9/25/2010   0.95862069  0.762068966
9/26/2010   0.693103448 0.703448276
9/27/2010   0.786206897 0.182758621
9/28/2010   1.355172414 0.124137931
9/29/2010   1.451724138 0.513793103
9/30/2010   1.134482759 0.9
10/1/2010   1.420689655 0.613793103
10/2/2010   0.755172414 -0.193103448
10/3/2010   0.148275862 -0.413793103
10/4/2010   0.65862069  0.106896552
10/5/2010   0.872413793 -0.282758621
10/6/2010   0.668965517 -0.279310345
10/7/2010   0.775862069 0.203448276
10/8/2010   0.968965517 -0.010344828
10/9/2010   0.903448276 0.224137931
10/10/2010  0.879310345 -0.086206897
10/11/2010  1.203448276 -0.051724138
10/12/2010  0.575862069 -0.072413793
10/13/2010  0.689655172 0.327586207
10/14/2010  0.603448276 -0.162068966
10/15/2010  1.096551724 0.313793103
10/16/2010  1.2 0.634482759
10/17/2010  1.103448276 0.437931034
10/18/2010  1.520689655 -0.368965517
10/19/2010  1.537931034 0.586206897
10/20/2010  1.1 0.651724138
10/21/2010  1.589655172 0.648275862
10/22/2010  1.027586207 0.162068966
10/23/2010  1.213793103 0.551724138
10/24/2010  1.444827586 0.668965517
10/25/2010  1.227586207 0.579310345
10/26/2010  1.5 0.231034483
10/27/2010  0.762068966 0.293103448
10/28/2010  1.651724138 -0.224137931
10/29/2010  0.010344828 -0.25862069
10/30/2010  1.724137931 0.365517241
10/31/2010  0.589655172 0.424137931
11/1/2010   0.9 -0.472413793
11/2/2010   1.286206897 0.034482759
11/3/2010   1.15862069  0.179310345
11/4/2010   1.568965517 0.403448276
11/5/2010   1.168965517 -0.003448276
11/6/2010   1.472413793 0.4
11/7/2010   1.165517241 0.696551724
11/8/2010   1.572413793 0.472413793
11/9/2010   1.317241379 0.144827586
11/10/2010  0.931034483 -0.137931034
11/11/2010  1.355172414 -0.017241379
11/12/2010  1.055172414 0.4
11/13/2010  1.668965517 0.220689655
11/14/2010  1.889655172 0.810344828
11/15/2010  2.275862069 0.172413793
11/16/2010  1.451724138 0.365517241
11/17/2010  2.544827586 0.44137931
11/18/2010  1.05862069  0.479310345
11/19/2010  0.737931034 0.255172414
11/20/2010  1.162068966 -7.11E-15
11/21/2010  1.562068966 0.193103448
11/22/2010  1.448275862 0.410344828
11/23/2010  1.951724138 0.679310345
11/24/2010  0.248275862 0.282758621
11/25/2010  1.648275862 0.196551724
11/26/2010  2.365517241 -0.172413793
11/27/2010  1.562068966 -0.131034483
11/28/2010  1.462068966 -0.120689655
11/29/2010  1.362068966 0.568965517
11/30/2010  1.293103448 0.710344828
12/1/2010   2.803448276 0.231034483
12/2/2010   4.34137931  0.717241379
12/3/2010   1.234482759 0.003448276
12/4/2010   1.486206897 -0.044827586
12/5/2010   1.162068966 0.220689655
12/6/2010   0.286206897 0.293103448
12/7/2010   1.175862069 0.189655172
12/8/2010   1.124137931 0.248275862
12/9/2010   0.486206897 -0.172413793
12/10/2010  0.996551724 0.420689655
12/11/2010  0.082758621 -0.248275862
12/12/2010  0.724137931 -0.093103448
12/13/2010  0.993103448 -0.006896552
12/14/2010  1.379310345 -0.020689655
12/15/2010  0.275862069 0.189655172
12/16/2010  0.772413793 0.068965517
12/17/2010  1.482758621 0.175862069
12/18/2010  1.15862069  0.548275862
12/19/2010  -0.137931034    0.562068966
12/20/2010  2.006896552 0.037931034
12/21/2010  0.424137931 0.293103448
12/22/2010  0.517241379 0.303448276
12/23/2010  0.817241379 0.027586207
12/24/2010  0.620689655 0.210344828
12/25/2010  1.703448276 0.368965517
12/26/2010  0.034482759 0.3
12/27/2010  0.713793103 0.027586207
12/28/2010  1.131034483 0.068965517
12/29/2010  2.806896552 -0.168965517
12/30/2010  1.117241379 0.296551724
12/31/2010  0.848275862 0.420689655
1/1/2011    1.810344828 0.086206897
1/2/2011    0.248275862 0.168965517
1/3/2011    2.027586207 0.903448276
1/4/2011    1.448275862 0.634482759
1/5/2011    1.013793103 0.186206897
1/6/2011    1.455172414 0.103448276
1/7/2011    0.820689655 0.65862069
1/8/2011    4.762068966 0.010344828
1/9/2011    1.986206897 0.724137931
1/10/2011   0.231034483 0.65862069
1/11/2011   2.220689655 0.45862069
1/12/2011   2.248275862 0.472413793
1/13/2011   1.137931034 0.479310345
1/14/2011   1.555172414 0.510344828
1/15/2011   1.268965517 1.255172414
1/16/2011   1.186206897 1.134482759
1/17/2011   0.772413793 0.713793103
1/18/2011   1.337931034 0.575862069
1/19/2011   -0.351724138    0.417241379
1/20/2011   0.586206897 0.724137931
1/21/2011   1.117241379 0.682758621
1/22/2011   -0.151724138    0.596551724
1/23/2011   -0.420689655    -0.010344828
1/24/2011   0.486206897 0.096551724
1/25/2011   -1.05862069 0.517241379
1/26/2011   0.275862069 0.613793103
1/27/2011   1.317241379 0.165517241
1/28/2011   0.44137931  0.568965517
1/29/2011   -1.120689655    0.362068966
1/30/2011   1.689655172 0.693103448
1/31/2011   -0.337931034    0.889655172
2/1/2011    -1.444827586    0.372413793
2/2/2011    -0.044827586    -0.075862069
2/3/2011    1.231034483 0.593103448
2/4/2011    0.796551724 0.565517241
2/5/2011    0.110344828 0.682758621
2/6/2011    0.84137931  0.496551724
2/7/2011    -0.55862069 0.720689655
2/8/2011    0.862068966 0.720689655
2/9/2011    0.117241379 0.382758621
2/10/2011   0.065517241 0.637931034
2/11/2011   0.8 1.072413793
2/12/2011   0.424137931 0.793103448
2/13/2011   1   0.85862069
2/14/2011   1.006896552 0.85862069
2/15/2011   -0.906896552    0.548275862
2/16/2011   0.324137931 0.503448276
2/17/2011   0.817241379 0.486206897
2/18/2011   0.137931034 0.706896552
2/19/2011   0.396551724 0.84137931
2/20/2011   -0.144827586    1.024137931
2/21/2011   0.9 1.162068966
2/22/2011   1.293103448 0.34137931
2/23/2011   1.603448276 -0.324137931",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

Note: I assume `df` is the `data.frame` containing your data.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(
        month = format(as.Date(DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = month, y = TMAX)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]