# Avoiding the sorting of X-axis and y-axis alphabetically in ggplot2 balloon plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to create a faceted balloon plot using the ggpubr package in R. However the x-axis and Yaxis automatically get sorted in alphabetic order as shown in the image link. I want the X-axis level order to be "B" "A" "D" "C" "E" in the final plot instead of "A" "B" "C" "D" "E". Please give me some suggestions.

[image]

```
library (readxl)
library(ggpubr)
obs=read_excel("baloon plot.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet2")
my_cols <- c("#0D0887FF", "#6A00A8FF", "#B12A90FF",
             "#E16462FF", "#FCA636FF", "#F0F921FF")
ggballoonplot(as.data.frame(obs), x = "Location", y = "Season",
              size = "NSE", fill = "NSE")+
  gradient_fill(c("blue", "white", "red"))+facet_wrap("Model")+
  guides(size = FALSE)+
  theme_gray() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=14, color = "black"))+
  scale_y_discrete(name = "Season") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Location")
```

Comment: Provide the data in `dput()` format. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Run `obs$Location <- factor(obs$Location, c("B", "A", "D", "C", "E"))` and then plot again.

Comment: See also these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755312/x-axis-with-more-than-one-factor-groups-ggplot & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214071/how-to-order-data-by-value-within-ggplot-facets. I would sort the seasons by water year order too

Comment: @RonakShah the command is not working in ggpubr package

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).